# Disable shortcut “Control+N” on Windows 7

Tags: windows, security, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-explorer

The problem that I want to solve is I have made one software on Windows: The software allow the user to use only this software on the computer. But when the user wants to load a file from mysoftware , he can do "Control + N" to open another Explorer windows and see everything on the disk. I don't want the user to use the other Explorer window.

On a Windows PC I would like to disable commands "control + N".

I would like to do something easy and not greedy in system resources. What should I do? Make a script in PowerShell? Do it in Cpp? VB?

By any chance, do you know if there is another way to do this without make a software, for example using a GPO?

Only with the software autohotkey does this work. But I don't want to install one software. :(

I have tried in PowerShellto make a script and to edit the Registry:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Mic​rosoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\​Policies\Explorer
```

I have Windows 7 Pro.

Answer (score 0):

#### Use third party software, such as the AutoHotKey solution you already have

According to the Microsoft doc [Disabling Windows Keyboard Shortcuts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa460734(v=winembedded.5).aspx):

> **To disable keyboard shortcuts**
>
> Use Ginastub.dll, set a policy in Group Policy Editor, or write low-level keyboard hooks. You can disable just about any key combination with one of these methods.

Unfortunately there are no Group Policies that disable the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> shortcut in Windows/File Explorer, (or any Ctrl-key based shortcuts for that matter).

Therefore, you need third party software that uses keyboard hooks. I would recommend AutoHotKey, which you've confirmed works.